# multiply two vectors - I want a scalar but I get a vector?

Tags: r, vector

This is my code:

```
a <-c(1,2,3)
b <-t(a)
print(a*b)
```

I would expect the result to be 14, since a column vector multiplied with a row vector with fitting dimensions should be a skalar.

However, I get:

> print (a*t(a))

```
 [,1] [,2] [,3]

[1,]    1    4    9
```

Hence the partial sums instead of the whole sum. How can I fix this?

Comment: A column vector multiplied with a row vector with fitting dimensions gives a (n x n) matrix: `matrix(a) %*% t(a)`

Comment: If you do not want what `crossprod` returns then you need to explain with more details what you do expect. Note that `crossprod` can be use to construct what is other domains is known as the scalar product or "dot-product". `crossprod(1:3)` returns the sum you apparently want.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If what you essentially want is the sum of the products, then all you need is `sum(a*a)`

Answer (score 21):

Two problems, multiplication in the wrong order, and the wrong multiply function.

```
> print(t(a)%*%a)
     [,1]
[1,]   14
```

Equivalently:

```
> a=matrix(c(1,2,3),ncol=3)
> print (a %*% t(a))
     [,1]
[1,]   14
```

Here `a` is a matrix of 1 row, three columns.

See `?"%*%"` and `?"*"`

Comment: Let's also mention you don't need to use `print` if you are in a session, which is probably the case.

Comment: and the `crossprod` and `tcrossprod` functions.

Comment: ahm - it is not a crossprodukt I am looking for.

Comment: Does any one know a R tutorial which does not spend to chapters on "how to make a vektor" but has a little more impakt on the real programming? for instance, if I have a matrix how to build sums over a number of vectors of the matrix and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this,

```
> a <-c(1,2,3)
> b <-t(a)

> b %*% a
```

Here, `%*%` acts as a matrix product.

Comment: Taking the transpose `t(a)` is not necessary, `a %*% a` works as well. Note that the `%*%` operator returns a 1x1 _matrix_ in this case, not a number.

Answer (score 0):

simply do this

```
a <-c(1,2,3)
> b<-t(a)
> b

> t(b)
```

then

> sum(a*t(b))
>   [1] 14

Comment: Why did this response get voted down? It appears to give the correct answer

Comment: Because it doesn't bring something new to [A_K's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13780062/8806649)